# Using Window.postmessage() to send a click event

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to create a single page web application which incorporates outlook's embedded calendar into an iframe. There will be two calendars, one which displays my shared calendar's current month and another one which looks at next month. I would like to use Window.postmessage() to send a click event to the outlook calendar to click the button which sets the calendar to view the next month. I have to use Window.postmessage() due to cross-origin policy as I cant access the elements in the calendars. Is this possible using Window.postmessage()? Is there any example available to show how its done?

Comment: Unless you control the code inside the iframe you can't create your own postMessage listeners or emitters within it. postMessage is only viable for cross origin when you control code in both locations

Comment: Quick answer: no this is not possible. Unless Outlook has implemented an `eventListener` that handles this kind of messages, but I hardly think it does.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response. I thought this was the case as all examples on the net shows implementation of codes within the iframe page. This might be off topic but I will ask anyways. Is there any way to achieve having outlook's embedded calendar load up on the next month without having me to click on the button? Is rendering your own calendar and retrieving data from outlook calendar REST API the only option?